# Ocaml Insertion Sort

Tags: ocaml

Input: Unsorted list / Output: Sorted list

My basic idea is insert an integer into the sorted list.

(I can sort the list if I could insert the first element into the sorted tails.)

I used "insert", which is thehelper function.

However, it gets overflow. Couuld anyone tell me what the problem is?

```
let rec sort (l: int list) : int list =
    match l with
        []->[]
      | x::[]->[x]
      | x1::x2::xs->let rec insert (n,dest) =
                            match dest with
                                []->[n]
                              | y::[]-> if n<y then [n;y] else [y;n]
                              | y1::y2::ys-> if y1<y2 then n::dest else y2::insert(y1,xs)
                    in insert(x1,sort(x2::xs)) ;;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line looks pretty wrong to me:

```
| y1::y2::ys-> if y1<y2 then n::dest else y2::insert(y1,xs)
```

It seems to me that you know your `ys` are sorted (by induction hypothesis). So you should be comparing `n` against your  `ys`, not your `ys` against each other. If you get this line straightened out things will probably improve.

For what it's worth, I suspect you only need to have two cases in your `match`. I don't see why you need to treat a 1-element list differently from any other non-null list.

Comment: Your advice is perfect. Thank you so much Jeffrey.

Answer (score 7):

Again, I have style suggestions:

- You should separate the two functions `sort` and `insert` because it would make it more readable and also because the `insert` function can be useful in itself.
- Why do you give a tuple as argument to the `insert` function? In OCaml, one would use currying and write `insert x l` instead of `insert(x,l)`. This would allow you to do partial application.
- Why do you restrict the type of your function to `int list -> int list`. Functions in OCaml can be polymorphic, so your function should have the more generic type `'a ist -> 'a list`.

Here is the code you obtain with all these corrections:

```
let rec insert x l =
  match l with
    | [] -> [x]
    | y::ys -> if x < y then x::y::ys else y::insert x ys

let rec sort l =
  match l with
    | [] -> []
    | x::xs -> insert x (sort xs)
```

Answer (score 2):

Always when asking such questions , it's hard for people to read such code and mostly they will ignore the post.
Like @Thomash said, first of all try to divide into smaller functions, this way it's easier to see where it fails.

you can "debug with your eye" this:

```
let rec insertion_sort el = function  
    | [] -> [el]
    | h::t as ls -> if el > h then h :: insert el t else (el :: ls) 

let sorted_list ls = List.fold_right insertion_sort ls []
```

Comment: List.fold_left could also be used instead of List.fold_right, you just need to change the parameter orders for `insert` and `insertion_sort`